# Alternative to Bash double bracket glob match

Tags: bash, test

Given

```
hasArgs=a:b:c:
x=b
if [[ ${hasArgs} = *$x:* ]] ; then …
```

I wish I could replace the above double brackets test with a less Bash specific  alternative (meaning no subshell/command etc.)

Parameter expansion does not help because it does not expend variables.

```
if [ "${hasArgs}" != "${hasArgs#$x:}" ] ; then …
```

Is there any simple (one line) solution that would fit this use case?

Comment: This is not bash specific but ksh specific. Double brackets have been introduced by ksh88.

Comment: I wanted to say POSIX compliant, but thank's I will remember where double brackets are coming from.

Comment: Double brackets have intentionally not put in to POSIX even though `ksh88` was the master for the POSIX shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can use the standard parameter expansions here (you were just missing the wildcard):

```
$ args=a:b:c:
$ x=b
$ echo "${args%$x:*}"
a:
$ if [ "$args" != "${args#*$x:}" ]; then echo 'b: is present'; fi
b: is present
```

(or equally `"${args%$x:*}"`)

The downside is that you need to have the colon after `b`, so `a:b` or a plain `b` wouldn't match, and it would also match `a:bb:c`. (`[[ $var = *$x:* ]]` as well as the obvious pattern match with `case` have the same disadvantage.)

Matching all of `b`, `b:c`, `a:b`, `a:b:c`, while not matching `a:bb:c` would be a bit more tricky. All I can think of is something like this:

```
args=a:b:c
x=b
IFS=:                   # affects globally
set -f                  # affects globally...
for x in $args; do
    if [ "$x" = "b" ]; then
        echo "b is present"
    fi
done
```

Unless you want to write all the cases out:

```
args=a:b:c
x=b
found=0
case "$args" in
    $x)     found=1;;
    $x:*)   found=1;;
    *:$x)   found=1;;
    *:$x:*) found=1;;
esac
if [ "$found" = 1 ]; then ...; fi
```

Much easier with regexes (in Bash):

```
args=b:c
x=b
if [[ $args =~ (^|:)$x(:|$) ]]; then
    echo "b found"
fi
```

Comment: So (some?) parameter expansion(s) actually evaluate variables in their pattern prior to expansion, I missed the wildcard. Since there will always have a colon after the _x_ variable, I can safely use this expression.

Comment: @Stphane, they all do, _on the right hand side_ that takes a string, not on the left part that takes a parameter name. So, `${x#$y}` works, but `${${x#foo}%bar}` doesn't. Except in zsh.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a one-liner, but this is quite readable and can be expanded to check for any number of arguments:

```
hasArgs="a:b:c"
x=b
case "$hasArgs" in
    *$x*)
        echo "$x is present"
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: I should have told about this but I already use a _case_ structure somewhere else in my script (meaning I am aware of the glob capability), this is the reason why I asked for a one-liner. But not everyone may be aware of this so your answer is surely welcome.

Answer (score 3):

The following will work in sh:

```
if echo "$hasArgs" | grep -q "$x"; then
```

Comment: Congrats on 10k!

Comment: Looks like a good alternative to `[` since both are external executables. (+ one-liner)